# What is the difference between the following two eBPF program types BPF_PROG_TYPE_SYSCALL and BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE?

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf

So I am assuming that `BPF_PROG_TYPE_SYSCALL` programs are triggered whenever a particular syscall is executed inside the kernel. Can't `BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE` ebpf programs be used for that purpose? kprobes can hook into any kernel function and syscalls are also kernel functions.

So what is the difference between the two types of programs and when to use which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would think that but actually `BPF_PROG_TYPE_SYSCALL` is a program type which can execute syscalls itself. https://lwn.net/Articles/854228/ It was introduced as an attempt to make one BPF program load another so the first program can be signed with a certificate. But it hasn't caught on very well yet as of writing this.

Indeed if you want to trigger on syscall execution, kprobes are the way to go.

Comment: Tracepoints also allow tracing syscall executions.